# What's the difference between Sequential and Synchronous Execution?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing, context-switch

If I understand it correctly:

**Asynchronous Execution** - *One task doesn't have to wait for another to finish*

**Concurrent Execution** - *Two tasks are being worked during a common time period (usually through context switching)*

But the opposites of both of those seem the same.

**Synchronous Execution** - *One task has to wait for another to finish before executing*

**Sequential Execution** - *Two tasks can't be worked on during a common time period. They have to be executed in order.*

It seems Synchronous and Sequential execution are the same thing. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe this will aid your understanding: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/144483/256197. The way I see it is that synchronous code is blocking, sequential code does not have to be - in the situation in which you run `task1` asynchronously, `await` its result and then start your subsequent tasks thereafter. Which results in sequential but asynchronous execution. Remember that each task usually relates to one thread.

Answer (score 2):

Sequential and synchronous are different things. Lets take for example next pseudocode:

pseudocode

{

do A

do B

do C

}

both sequential and synchronous will do task in order A->B->C. The difference is in the way they can do it.

Only way synchronous can do it is to start executing task A, block everything and wait till the task is finished. After that it proceeds to task B. You can imagine this as execution of all tasks on one single thread.

On the other hand with sequential execution we can start execution of task A on thread 1 in background. After is finishes we can start executing task B on our main thread (lets say thread 2).
We have same end result, but as you can see the process is different

Answer (score 0):

For all intents and purposes, *especially* if you're a novice/junior programming, you should pretty much consider:

Sequential, synchronous, blocking, to be interchangeable terms.

Concurrent, asynchronous, non-blocking, to be interchangeable terms.

But asynchrony and parallelism are not synonyms at all, and while they both fall under the umbrella term of *concurrency*, they are very two different ways of achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite an interesting question, but AFAIK it comes down to history / English moreso than it does programming. This is based on material I've read online, not a linguist / historian, and certainly didn't coin either term.

In a language like JavaScript, "synchronous" code happens "sequentially" and "asynchronous" code *seems* to happen "concurrently" (though this isn't technically true for JS -- it's single threaded, so even async code is processed "in an order"). This seems at odds with their English definitions:

- Synchronous: existing or occurring at the same time.
- Asynchronous: not existing or occurring at the same time.

The missing link here is "what" is synchronous vs asynchronous. As far as I can tell, it's not referring to the code: instead, it's the communication. Synchronous web code goes: client  server  client  server ... a better way to describe it would be "synchronized." Whereas the inverse is unordered and irregular communication, the server & client are "not synchronized".

This extends to any sync / async communication. Synchronous: the "request and response" happen as part of the same interaction, at the same time -- the code must necessarily block while this happens. Asynchronous: the "request" is sent immediately & the "response" is received and acknowledged sometime in the future, at a different time -- the code *needn't* necessarily block while this happens.

---

The best external explanation I found online -- though I can't speak to its veracity -- comes from this Twitter reply from Robert Graham (@ErrataRob), quoted here verbatim: https://twitter.com/ErrataRob/status/1732867690459468278

> **Short answer:**
>
> It refers to sender/receiver being synchronize with each other. Thus
> the sender does A,B,C, and the receiver sees A,B,C -- rather than
> B,A,C.
>
> When the sender/receiver are synchronized with each other, the
> receiver is thus expecting things to arrive in order, one after the
> other. It's expecting a certain behavior from the sender.
>
> It's not meant to see things from only the point of view of the
> receiver -- but from the point of view of the sender and receiver
> together, they are synchronized with each other.
>
> **Long answer:**
>
> Back in the 1960s, this described serial communication. You had a
> separate "CLOCK" line that kept both sender and receiver synchronized.
> Then you had "asynchronous" communications, were bytes of data could
> arrive unexpectedly and at whim. The receiver had no expectation about
> how things might arrive.
>
> Fast forward to the 2000s. The early "Apache" web server created a
> thread/process for each connection. That thread expected things to
> arrive in a certain order from the sender.
>
> But operating-systems aren't built to juggle more than 1000 (thousand)
> concurrent threads/processes, so this was an enormous limitation on
> the server. Once too many people tried to create connections to the
> server, it would fall over, failing to do any useful work.
>
> Servers switched models. Instead of a thread per connection, they used
> a single thread (well, single thread per CPU). The thread waits for
> packets to arrives, then handles each packet separately/independently.
>
> In this model, there is no expectation of the order of things
> arriving, no real synchronization between sender and receiver. We call
> it "asynchronous", because it describes very well what we are doing
> compared to all the other uses of that word in the history of computer
> science.
>
> Retroactively, we call the Apache model "synchronous". It's not
> actually a good use of the word, as there's not really that much
> synchronization between sender/receiver, we use it primarily to say
> "non-asynchronous".
>
> Of course, asynchronous sees things only from the point of view of the
> receiver, where there many incoming events at the same time. So you
> see the confusion when from the point of view of Apache, seeing things
> only from the side of the server, of things happening in sequence. But
> the proper view is to see the Apache thread handling a connection is
> synchronized with a sending thread on the other side of the network.
> https://twitter.com/soychotic/status/1732786087922192518

See Also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102150/synchronous-events-and-synchronized-swimmers-what-is-the-difference